# Tab fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

[image]

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int s = this.fragments.size();
            return this.fragments.size();
        }
    }
```

Text here:
 if i go from tab4 to tab2 than first control go to tab2 than it go to tab1. i could not understand how can it go to tab1?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I got your question: Are you asking why it goes to tab1 when you click on tab2?

Comment: when i click on tab4 , after tab on tab4 , than i tab on tab2 , tab1 i called.

Comment: mean after tab4 , tab2 i called but tab1 fragment i called.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you're trying to cache the fragments into memory by using the **this** context. But you're not supposed to, **FragmentPagerAdapter** class should do it for you.  Google webpage and sample @ [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html). Look at sample code on that page.
Code snippet:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

Notes:

- Notice the call to method `newInstance`. Implement it in your Fragment.
- Need to define a fragment subclass, sample uses ArrayListFragment.

Comment: ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);

Comment: why we create its instane?

Comment: newInstance method is important, without it, at best you can only get 1 same fragment for ALL the tabs. Adding code for newInstance() is easy, you don't have to add code for Bundle, if you don't want to. Another reason is this is the common way that other developers are coding and expect. All newInstance() does is ....new Fragment().